# Image size of 447x412817 pixels is too large. error for sns.scatterplot

Tags: python

I have a dataset with 2 features with the name pos_x and pos_y and I need to scatter plot the clustered data done with DBScan. Here is what I have tried for it:

```
colors=['purple','red','blue','green']
    Data = []
    dataset = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/file_name.csv')
    Datadb = dataset[["pos_x","pos_y"]]
    dbscan=DBSCAN()
    clusters =dbscan.fit(Datadb.to_numpy())
    p = sns.scatterplot(data=Datadb, x="pos_x", y="pos_y", hue=clusters.labels_, legend="full", palette="deep")
    sns.move_legend(p, "upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1.17, 1.2), title='Clusters')
    plt.show()
```

but it shows me the following error:

ValueError: Image size of 447x412817 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

I even added the following parameters into sns.scatterplot but I get the error that scatterplot doesn't have height parameter.

height=4.27, aspect=5.7/4.27

ّI also wrote the following code:

```
p = sns.scatterplot(data=Datadb, x="pos_x", y="pos_y", hue=clusters.labels_, legend="full", palette="deep")
    p.fig.set_figwidth(6.27)
    p.fig.set_figheight(7.7)
    sns.move_legend(p, "upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1.17, 1.2), title='Clusters')
    plt.show()
```

but I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'fig'
```

Appreciate if anyone helps me how can I set the size for sns.scatterplot because my dataset is huge, every time I run my code, it takes a lot of time to execute!

Answer (score 0):

Your `p` is not a `Figure` but a `'AxesSubplot'`. Under the hood, if not given any `Axis` object, it creates one and returns the same.

You can do

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (6.27,7.7)

ax = sns.scatterplot(ax = ax)
```

Then use all the available functions for [Matplotlib Subplot Axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes)

For the image size of `447x412817`, you should clip the values in a range or maybe sue a different scale. You must be having ranges range too broad. Maybe you can normalise them or so. (just talking at the top my head)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain more about using all the available functions for Matplotlib Subplot Axis?

Comment: Please just check the link given above. You'll see an expanded list of functions for the same such as `.pie(), .hline(), .set_xlim, .set_ylim(), .set_title()` etc